# in soring boot how to create a drop down selection list, and the content list is from controller?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jsp

I'm learning Spring Boot and trying to build a web application, but I don't understand how to retrieve data from controller to .jsp.

```
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Category"></label>
                <select class="form-control"
                        id="Category"
                        name="Category">

                    <c:forEach items="${catigoryies}" var="Category">
                        <option value="${category.id}">${category.name}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
        </div>
```

this is my controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/init-quiz-list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCategory(HttpSession session, ModelMap model) {
        List<Category> cate = quizService.getCategory();
        model.addAttribute("CategoryList", cate);
        return "init-quiz";
    }
}
```

[this is file diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4OvF.png)

then I have some question in my code:

or what is the best way to present date that I got from mysql in a prebuild jsp, instead of return a viewandmodle?

Answer (score 0):

well, finally I figured it out by myself.
A drop-down selection list can be achieved by (jsp)   we can easy google it

```
            <select class="form-select"
                    id="CategoryID"
                    name="CategoryID">
                <c:forEach items="${CategoryList}" var="category">
                    <option value="${category.getId()}">${category.getName()}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
```

get content from the controller we need to add attributes to ModelMap  (for current page) or   HttpSession (for current session, unless server invalidate your session), RedirectAttributes (for one-time use on redirecting tp another page)

```
       @PostMapping(value = "/ac")
   public String postTmp(HttpSession session, ModelMap model, RedirectAttributes redir) {
       QuizSubmition quizA = new QuizSubmition();
       session.setAttribute("quizA",quizA);
       model.addAttribute("quizA", quizA);
       redir.addFlashAttribute("quizA", quizA);
        return "/abcd";
   }
```

and get in jsp just using

```
    ${quizA.getwhat()}
```

answer my own question just for other fresh noobs like me can save some time.

Tell me if there is anything that I understand wrong.